# Boxplot with Jitter Points - How do I use gradient color with non discrete data for the jitter points?

Tags: r, colors, gradient

Quick question. I'm using the following R code to create a boxplot chart, with jitter points overlaid:

```
    ##########################Business Risk and FFO/Debt##########################
ratings <- read.csv(file.path("C:/","RawRatingDataPub.csv"), sep=",")
ratings$BusRisk <- factor(ratings$BusinessRisk,
                          levels=c("Excellent","Strong","Satisfactory"))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(ratings, aes(x=BusRisk, y=FFO_Debt))+ 
  scale_color_discrete(name  ="Rating", 
                       breaks=c("AA-","A+","A","A-","BBB+","BBB","BBB-","BB+","BB","-BB","B+","B","B-","CCC+"),
                       labels=c("AA-","A+","A","A-","BBB+","BBB","BBB-","BB+","BB","-BB","B+","B","B-","CCC+"))+
  scale_shape_discrete(name="Industry")+  
  geom_boxplot(fill="cornflowerblue",
               color="black", notch=FALSE)+
  geom_jitter(aes(colour = Rating, shape = Industry))+
  geom_rug(side="r", color="cornflowerblue")+
  xlab("\nBusiness Risk")+
  ylab("FFO to Debt")+
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
ggsave(file="BRFFO.pdf")
```

I basically like the output. I'd post and image...but I don't have enough points, so this link should work, http://postimg.org/image/8bcovyqwn/.

You can find the data source at the following link, https://www.dropbox.com/s/vog1qaczvx9i2cf/RawRatingDataPub.csv?dl=0

However, I'm wondering if there is a way I can get the ratings to be colored on a gradient color scheme, green to yellow.

I've been at this while so any help would be appreciated.

-T

Comment: Please add something to your question that indicates what language and/or app this is.

Comment: You need to post a dataset: either as code to simulate or a link to an accessible location with the data, such as Github.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this, https://www.dropbox.com/s/vog1qaczvx9i2cf/RawRatingDataPub.csv?dl=0

Comment: you could try `scale_colour_brewer(palette = "YlGn")`

Comment: I would prefer to have a simulated dataset. That way the question is self contained and even people on Mars with little access to internet will be able to chip in.

Comment: scale_colour_brewer(name  ="Rating",type="seq", palette =3, labels=c("AA-","A+","A","A-","BBB+","BBB","BBB-","BB+","BB","-BB","B+","B","B-","CCC+"))


Thanks scoa, that worked perfectly!